# Alter user password via jdbc. Problems with passes containing question marks

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a problem with altering a users password when the password contains a question mark char. I do not encounter this problem with any other char so far, it seems specific to the question mark char.

If i alter a users password in sqlplus using the following sql:

`Alter user Stephen identifed by "NewPassword?" REPLACE "OldPassword";`

Then it changes the pass successfully and I can login using the new pass 'NewPassword?'.

However if I execute the same SQL via jdbc:

`final String query = "ALTER user Stephen identified by \"NewPassword?\" REPLACE \"OldPassword\"";

stmt.executeUpdate(query);`

I then cannot log in using the pass 'NewPassword?'.

Checking the hashcodes for the password when entered via sqlplus and jdbc show that they are different.
Somehow when I run the statement in jdbc it is entering something other than 'NewPassword?'.

I don't seem to have any problems with the following passwords:
NewPassword, NewPassword\, NewPassword'. It just seems to be the question mark that is causing problems.
Debugging shows the code point (dec) is 63 for the question mark so it doesn't look like its being changed midway.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this behaviour?
I'm at a loss at the moment, I'm considering preventing passes with question marks to bypass this problem for now.

Comment: Which DB version? Which JDBC driver version? What does `stmt.getClass().getName()` say?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this at the start.  
db version = Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production,    
driver version = 10.2.0.4.0,  
stmt.getClass().getName() = oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CStatement_Proxy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use JDBC to change the password of an Oracle user you need to do two things:

- put the password directly in the SQL string (bind parameters cannot be used),
- disable escape processing.

You can't use bind variables because the username and password are not sent to the database as single-quoted strings.

The `?` in the SQL string is being taken as a bind variable placeholder, and because of this the SQL string is getting mangled at some point by Oracle JDBC.  Disabling escape processing on the statement stops this from happening.  Try:

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
s.setEscapeProcessing(false);
s.executeUpdate("ALTER user Stephen identified by \"newPassword?\" replace \"oldPassword\"");
```

If you are setting the password programmatically, your code should also ensure that the new and old passwords do not contain any `"` characters, to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks Pourquoi. This does sound like exactly what it is doing. I will give your solution a try :)

Comment: From [`PreparedStatement` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setEscapeProcessing%28boolean%29): "Note: Since prepared statements have usually been parsed prior to making this call, disabling escape processing for PreparedStatements objects will have no effect"

Comment: @VitoShadow: thanks for your comment.  I've updated my answer to use a plain `Statement`, as that appears to be what the asker is using.  Incidentally, I can't reproduce the asker's issue any more - perhaps it has been fixed in a later version of the Oracle JDBC driver than what I was using at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Try implementing it using a `PreparedStatement` and see if you get the same problem. Question marks are used in `PreparedStatements` as placeholders, so maybe the JDBC driver is getting confused. It *shouldn't*, but might be worth checking.

```
PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement("ALTER user Stephen identified by ? replace ?");
p.setString(1, "NewPassword?");
p.setString(2, "OldPassword");
p.execute();
```

If this works then it's probably a bug in the driver.

Comment: You can't use placeholders with `ALTER USER x IDENTIFIED BY y`, at least not with Oracle.  The username and password aren't sent to the database as single-quoted strings.

Comment: Ah. This probably won't work then. Still, the idea that the question marks were being misinterpreted may still be correct.