# SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to INSERT records to an Oracle DB using PreparedStatement but I only get this error. At this point, my effort to overcome it far outweighs my progress so another set of eyes might help. Where is the invalid character?

A lot of what I've found suggests that a trailing "**`;`**" inside of your sql String can be the culprit, but I haven't had one in my statement from the outset.

My connection itself, which **works** perfectly at several other places in the program:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty( "user", username );
props.setProperty( "password", password );
props.setProperty( "defaultRowPrefetch", "10" );
props.setProperty( "defaultBatchValue", "10" );
props.setProperty( "processEscapes", "false" );

DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL_SVC, props);
```

The way I'd like to get it done (except that I would wrap it in a method that accepts three Strings) but it throws a **SQLSyntaxErrorException**

```
String INSERT_BIKE = "INSERT INTO RACEBIKES ( BIKENAME , COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN , COST ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? )";
PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement( INSERT_BIKE );
preStatement.setString(1, "JHT");
preStatement.setString(2, "USA");
preStatement.setInt(3, 2500);
preStatement.executeUpdate();    // ORA-00911: invalid character error
```

This **works**, but defeats the purpose of using PreparedStatement since the parameters are hard-coded:

```
String INSERT_BIKE = "INSERT INTO RACEBIKES ( BIKENAME , COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN , COST ) VALUES ( 'JHT' , 'USA' , '2500' )";
PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement( INSERT_BIKE );
preStatement.executeUpdate();
```

**Works**. However, I understand that concatenating variables with single and double quotes also isn't really the best way because PreparedStatement should alleviate us from having to deal with that part of the syntax:

```
String value1 = "JHT";
String value2 = "USA";
int value3 = 2500;
String INSERT_BIKE = "INSERT INTO RACEBIKES ( BIKENAME , COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN , COST ) VALUES ( '" + value1 + "', '" + value2 + "', '" + value3 + "' )";
PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement( INSERT_BIKE );
preStatement.executeUpdate();
```

**Fails** with a **SQLSyntaxErrorException**. So even if code quotation syntax myself, I'm still unable to place those variables in the preStatement.setString(), which would at least allow a little flexibility.

```
String INSERT_BIKE = "INSERT INTO RACEBIKES ( BIKENAME , COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN , COST ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? )";
PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement( INSERT_BIKE );
preStatement.setString(1, "' + value1 + '");
preStatement.setString(2, "' + value2 + '");
preStatement.setInt(3, "' + value3 + '");
preStatement.executeUpdate();    // ORA-00911: invalid character error
```

**Fails.** Enclosing the placeholders in my String with single quotes results in **SQLException**.

```
String INSERT_BIKE = "INSERT INTO RACEBIKES ( BIKENAME , COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN , COST ) VALUES ( '?' , '?' , '?' )";
PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement( INSERT_BIKE );
preStatement.setString(1, "JHT");
preStatement.setString(2, "USA");
preStatement.setInt(3, 2500);
preStatement.executeUpdate();    // invalid column index
```

**Fails.** Enclosing the two `String` (but not the `int`) placeholders in my String with single quotes results in **SQLException**.

```
String INSERT_BIKE = "INSERT INTO RACEBIKES ( BIKENAME , COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN , COST ) VALUES ( '?' , '?' , ? )";
PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement( INSERT_BIKE );
preStatement.setString(1, "JHT");
preStatement.setString(2, "USA");
preStatement.setInt(3, 2500);
preStatement.executeUpdate();    // invalid column index
```

This **doesn't fail, but doesn't write to database** either (even though I haven't disabled auto-commit).

```
String INSERT_BIKE = "INSERT INTO RACEBIKES ( BIKENAME , COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN , COST ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? )";
PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement( INSERT_BIKE );
preStatement.setString(1, "JHT");
preStatement.setString(2, "USA");
preStatement.setInt(3, 2500);
preStatement.executeBatch();
```

I've also tried all matter of escapes with backslashes, double backslashes, backticks, [quitsies, no-startsies, erasies, double-stamps, and tofus-make-it-true](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RKDifoyra8)! Maybe somebody out there knows the voodoo that will help me?!

Comment: In order to use `executeBatch()`, you need to call `addBatch()` (for each row) before. I guess then it'll fail, too.

Comment: What strikes me is that your third parameter is an int, but in your working examples, you use single-quotes, too. What happens if you leave them out?
If that doesn't work either, I assume your `COST` column is `VARCHAR`, too.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to include that case in my original post. Using executeBatch() was more of a shot in the dark that I tried because I had set a batchValue in my properties object. In this case the user can only update a single record at a time. But including addBatch() just above executeBatch() still results in **BatchUpdateException: ORA-00911: invalid character**.

Comment: The `COST` column is a `NUMBER` but removing the single-quotes throws ORA-00911.

Comment: You mean, executing `"INSERT INTO RACEBIKES ( BIKENAME , COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN , COST ) VALUES ( 'JHT' , 'USA' , 2500 )"` results in an ORA-00911, too?
Could you please alter your first (original) snippet to this: `preStatement.setString(3, "2500");` and try again?

Comment: Correct, without quotes around 2500 I get ORA-0911. Executing the line the way you suggested also throws ORA-0911.

Comment: Did you also try the `preStatement.setString(3, "2500");` stuff?

Comment: Yeah, I tried `preStatement.setString(3, "2500");` too and it also threw ORA-00911. [@skirsch](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2194248/skirsch) thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a reason why you have `props.setProperty( "processEscapes", "false" );`?

I believe that this turns off the ability to use `?` as bind parameter placeholder.  I believe that if escape processing is enabled, JDBC does some 'magic' with the `?` placeholders before passing the SQL string to Oracle.  Otherwise, the `?` character is sent to the database as-is.

There are occasional uses for disabling escape processing.  I used it in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4518750/) to a question involving `?` characters in passwords.  I believe it can be disabled at the connection or the statement level; to re-enable escape processing on a PreparedStatement, try calling `preStatement.setEscapeProcessing(true);`.  I would expect the first of your failing examples to succeed with this option set.

As for your failing examples, those with unescaped `?`s will cause problems as `?` is not a valid character in SQL. Surrounding `?` in single quotes turns it into a single-character string, so it wouldn't be a bind parameter even if escape processing is enabled.  I can't say why the last one doesn't write to the database.

Comment: But why does `INSERT INTO RACEBIKES (BIKENAME, COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN, COST) VALUES ('JHT','USA', 2500)` fail?

Comment: Very Nice! Calling `preStatement.setEscapeProcessing(true);` was the answer. I had it set to false because in some other places I was using this same instance for some hard-coded queries where escape processing isn't necessary. In those cases, I believed omitting those calls was more efficient but never figured that it was also preventing me from using PreparedStatement as it was intended. [@luke-woodward](http://stackoverflow.com/users/48503/luke-woodward), many thanks for your insight!

Comment: @skirsch: which example do you mean?  I don't see why the SQL you've put in your comment should fail.

Comment: @es0329: glad to hear my answer helped.  I can't say whether disabling escape processing improves performance much (to be honest, I'd be surprised if it did), but the only way to find out would be to benchmark it.  Time how long it takes your database to run through a load of your hard-coded queries, once with escape processing enabled and once with it disabled, and see what the time difference between the two runs is.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: I meant a slight variation of the second example - with the single-quotes removed around `2500`. es0329 was getting an ORA-00911 for that also. And even with escape processing turned off, I don't understand why this fails. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @skirsch: I suspect this is in reference to the fifth and sixth comments to the question.  I can't honestly believe that you would get an ORA-00911 error for that.  I can only assume that there has been some confusion between you and es0329.